# Kettle Weka Scoring Deserializing Error

Tags: weka, kettle

I am trying to load a Weka model in kettle to score incoming data and I am receiving the following error:

"An error occured reading a transformation from the repository

Problem de-serializing model file using supplied file name!"

The Weka version I have is 3.7.9. Using Kettle 4.4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Weka's serialization format has changed between 3.6 and the later 3.7 versions, if you're using an older version of the Weka scoring plugin in Kettle (likely if you're running 4.4.0), you'd need to also use an older version of Weka.

I'd try a few versions in 3.6 (3.6.11 to start, then maybe 3.6.5, 3.6.0) if you're dead set on using Kettle 4.4.0

Otherwise you could try upgrading Kettle (specifically the Weka scoring plugin) to something released around the same time as the Weka release you want to run.